# Why does the const clause not work if I try to use it when I want to protect the modification of a vector?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, cc

In the book I am studying it says that if I pass a vector to a function, the name of the vector is always treated as a pointer.
In fact it's so.
But I can't understand why in the first function the const clause is allowed by the compiler, while in the second function (where I use pointers to search for the maximum value between the elements) no.
In the functions I would simply like to protect against the modification of the vector.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_largest(const int a[], int n);
int find_largest_with_pointer(const int *vettore, int n);

int main(void) {
    int my_number[] = {5, 7, 90, 34, 12};
    int n = sizeof(my_number) / sizeof(my_number[0]);
    int *pmy_number = my_number;

    printf("%d\n", find_largest(my_number, n));
    printf("%d\n", find_largest(pmy_number, n));
    printf("%d\n", find_largest_with_pointer(my_number, n));
    printf("%d\n", find_largest_with_pointer(pmy_number, n));

    return 0;
}

int find_largest(const int a[], int n) {
    int i, max;
    max = a[0];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(a[i] > max)
            max = a[i];

    return max;
}

int find_largest_with_pointer(const int *vettore, int n) {
    int *i, max = *vettore;

    for(i = vettore; i < vettore + n; i++)
        if(*i > max)
            max = *i;

    return max;
}
```

Comment: The compiler error should tell you quite clearly what you're doing wrong and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `vettore` is a pointer to `const int`, you must make `i` have the same type.

```
const int *i;
int max = *vettore;

for(i = vettore; i < vettore + n; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short Version: Adding a const qualifier will address the compiler warning.

```
int find_largest_with_pointer(const int *vettore, int n) {
//    int *i, max = *vettore;
    const int *i ;
    int max = *vettore;
    ...
}
```

**Long Version:**

In the second function, you use two variables. Expanding the code a little bit

```
   int *i ;l
   it max = a[0] ;
   for (
       i = vettore;
       i < vettore + n;
       i++
   ) { ... }
```

Note the line `i = vettore`, which will attempt to copy the 'const int * vettore`into non-const 'int *i`. This has the potential of allowing modification to the const vector (e.g. `*i = 5`), and the compiler complain:

```
c.c:33:11: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     for(i = vettore; i < vettore + n; i++)
```

Solution is simple: add const qualifier on `const int *i`. See above.